# How to get text input (autocomplete="new-password") on robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

I want to do a test on input text :

```
<input _ngcontent-c21="" autocomplete="new-password" class="form-control modal-input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" id="prenom" name="prenom" type="text" xpath="1">
```

my code is:

```
Click Element   xpath://span[contains(text(),'Nous contacter')]
Sleep   2
Location Should Be      ${contactPageUrl}
Click Element   xpath://input[@id='prenom']
Sleep   2
Element Text Should Be      xpath://input[@id='prenom']     ${USERFIRSTNAME}
```

But i'm getting a result saying that the input text is empty even tho is not, is it because of the `autocomplete="new-password"` ?

Answer (score 0):

That is an `input` field of `type="text"`, but you did not typed any text into it. If you expect the field to be auto-filled  with `${USERFIRSTNAME}`, then there is missing the triggering of Angular action. This may be a timing problem, you did not wait for the field to be auto-filled, or you need to click the element to trigger it.

Comment: i tried it before but i was getting the same result

Comment: Are you using AngularJS library? If you do the workflow manually, does it auto-fill? When?

Comment: No i'm not using AngularJS library

Comment: What do you receive if you try to `Get Text | prenom` or `Get Element Attribute | prenom | value`?

Also note that `id` locator can be used without specifying strategy, and that you should change `Sleep`s to `Wait Until` keywords

Comment: @asprtrmp i'm getting an empty string. I tried to trigger the input  and wait but it's same result.